# How to interact with a Command Prompt / Console Application via a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, command-prompt, windows-server-2012

I am trying to create an app to manage a server application from a video game.

For unknown reasons, the server application provided as-is is a painful command prompt terminal/console with very limited interaction :

- impossibility to highlight content in the aim of copying information ;
- impossibility to paste content into the input command (we have to write everything down) ;
- no visible cursor while writing or trying to move arround the command line to be executed
- etc...

Here is a screenshot : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/49/1417625953-server-console.png

So, I would like to know if there is any possible way to catch what is happening in this terminal and more importantly if there is a way to interact with it while using my custom application (`Windows  Sevrer 2012`).

Example of possible interactions from a end-user :

- Being able to click on buttons, such as "Show Public Server Name" which will ask the terminal using the correct command-line (`get_server_name`) and catch the terminal output ;
- Being able to modify server properties on the fly such as "Set New Server Name" with a `TextBox` and a button that when hit, will send the corresponding command-line with the correct argument to the terminal (`set_server_name <server_name>`)

As you can see, this is a straightfoward application, nothing really fancy here.

I believe it is possible because, for that particular game, there exist a few script with advance features like administrative tools (ban, kick etc...). So I know there is a way to interact.

So how can I interact with this terminal command prompt console application ?

Thanks !

Notes :

- the console application is that of a traditionnal executable Windows binary ;
- I use a `bat` file to execute the server and there is an "interaction" here I wrote a `-r` flag to indicate the terminal which configuration file to read ;
- I really would like to develop a `Windows Store App` for `Server 2012` in `c#` but ready to use other existing solutions ;